# Advanced search based on number of answers has different behavior between 0 and >0 numbers

Tags: support, status-bydesign, search

When searching on Stack Overflow using the "answers:N" syntax, there appears to be a bug.
When you search for `answers:1`, it returns ~360200 results.
When searching for `answers:2` it returns ~270300 results.
However, searching for `answers:0` returns ~18700 results.

Since the wording states that it will return questions with "N or more answers" the search for 0 should return more than searches for 1, not significantly less.

Comment: That's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if "answers:0" is specifically special-cased or not, but it has traditionally been used to return unanswered questions. In other words, 0 really returns questions with 0 answers.

Any other number behaves as *n*-or-more. 0 behaves as 0, and that aspect is by design. (Many of us want a way to find unanswered questions.)

However, I do think that the help regarding that should definitely be updated to reflect that fact.